# Como recuperar informação da URL laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho a seguinte rota:

```
# Minha rota para cadastro de pessoas ao escolher um plano
Route::get('/cadastrar/{plano}', function($plano = 'silver'){
    # Checa se o plano existe
    if (array_search($plano, ['silver', 'gold', 'diamond']) === false)
        # Caso não exista, usa o "silver" como padrão 
        return redirect()->route('cadastrar', ['plano' => 'silver']);
    # Retorna a View para o usuário
    return view('auth.cadastrar');
# Condições de existência para o campo plano
})->where(['plano' => '[a-z]+'])->name('cadastrar');
```

Mas eu preciso que dentro da View eu possa recuperar o nome do plano escolhido, por exemplo:

```
# http://exemplo.com/cadastrar/silver
# Parabéns você escolheu o plano {{$plano}}
```

E eu gostaria de saber se o jeito que eu fiz essa rota é o melhor, ou existe algum jeito mais profissional, obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, veja na documentação [Laravel: Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views)

Basta passar um array no segundo argumento na chamada da `view`.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como implementar dentro do seu código.

```
# Minha rota para cadastro de pessoas ao escolher um plano
Route::get('/cadastrar/{plano}', function($plano = 'silver'){
    # Checa se o plano existe
    if (array_search($plano, ['silver', 'gold', 'diamond']) === false)
        # Caso não exista, usa o "silver" como padrão 
        return redirect()->route('cadastrar', ['plano' => 'silver']);
    # Retorna a View para o usuário
    return view('auth.cadastrar', compact('plano'));
# Condições de existência para o campo plano
})->where(['plano' => '[a-z]+'])->name('cadastrar');
```

Answer (score -1):

Percebi algumas práticas que não são muito aconselháveis, como por exemplo uma verificação(if) dentro do arquivo de rotas do Laravel.

1° Passo - Retirar a logica desse arquivo e passar para dentro de uma função na model. Onde realmente devem ficar sua regras de negócio.

2° Passo  -  Para recuperar qual plano foi escolhido você pode tanto retornar para a view uma variável ou criar uma variável de sessão session('Plano_Escolhido') atráves da controller.